# How do i add a Variable into my HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add Ids in my Javascript that get into my html as well so i can assign the Id to onclick remove.The Div has Images in it that are not Uploaded in the DB.Basically its a preview with a little Button on it that marks "x" as in delete.The x removes itself onclick but i want to remove the div that the x is in hence i need Ids so i can delete the Image+the "x". I have everything Set up except the Id that goes into the newly made Divs so i can make a good remove Action for it.

I tried to add a Variable with .html to the Div i want to assign the Ids in but it doesnt work. It says the Variable is not assigned.

JS:

```
  $(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;


            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {

                    $('<div class="previewdeleter position-relative" data-item-id-div="[i]" style="height:200px;width: 200px; display: inline-block; position: relative !important;">' +
                        '<img alt="" src='+event.target.result+' style="height:200px;width: 100%; display: inline-block;">' +
                        '<div class="position-absolute" style="top: 0;right: 0;">' +
                        '<img src="/x.png" class="image-deletepreview" style="height: 20px; display: inline-block;"></div></div>')
                        .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);


                    $('.image-deletepreview').on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var deletepreview = $(this).remove();
                        console.log(deletepreview);

                    });

                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i],);
            }

        }


    };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="previewHolder" data-item-id-div="[i]" multiple=""  class="previewdeleter position-relative">
                    <div class="position-absolute delete-image">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you rephrase it? Perhaps you are looking for https://www.journaldev.com/4656/jquery-get-attribute-set-remove ?

Comment: Your dom is updated dynamically (with Javascript), and you need to call click on an element that is a parent of the dynamically created div. as a rough example. `$('body').on('click', '.image-deletepreview', function(e) {...});` try this

Comment: _“but i want to remove the div that the x is in hence i need Ids”_ - no, you don’t. Stuff like this should be handled by making use of the relation elements have to each other in the DOM tree, not by stamping IDs all over the place like a graffiti artist running amok. Go read up on jQuery tree traversal methods such as `.parent()` / `.parents()`

Comment: @Kajbo could u tell me what part is confusing? Basically i want the images that  are being inputted to get a Id. That Id should be declared at my Javascript.

Comment: @AndrejsGubars sorry i am confused. So far i have exactly what you told me to have. The on click is used on the image-deletepreview. The Function i will add there is to remove the Id on which the image-deletepreview is on. That is why i literally just need to add the Id for each Div that contains the IMG and the image-deletepreview.

Comment: @04FS oh wow i did not even consider that. So basically i can just remove the Container of the IMG and the image-deletepreview just by saying the parent of IMG should be removed by clicking on image-deletepreview. Thank you so much. I feel pretty dumb right now since this makes perfect Sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i simply changed the Code:

```
                    var deletepreview = $(this).remove();
```

To :

```
                        var deletepreview = $(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

What i did is instead of Ids i just took the Parent of the Image i wanted to delete . In this Case i had to go 2 Parents up because i have 2 Images on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, but as per my understating you can use
DOM to create the element and add the id,

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'myid';
```